# application level component property change

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I need to change the layout componet value from page level template.

[image]

like in picture x.hbs may vary according to route.each spesific route may have add to cart button and when add to cart button click the layout component price should be updated.

how to do something like this in emberjs way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manage global state you should use an [service](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/applications/services/#toc-toggle).

However for you use-case I would just rely on the `store`-Service provided by `ember-data`. You probably should create a [model](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/models/defining-models/) for your `shopping-cart-item`s. Then you can do something like `store.findAll('shopping-cart-item')` in your application routes model hook. In the application controller you can get the sum with a simple Computed Property.
Now if you add items to your cart, ember-data will keep everything in sync.

Maybe checkout [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/7d5ffd6978af12b404804299997e58a6?openFiles=controllers.index.js%2C) for demonstration.